# Statistical outlier detection in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, std, mean, outliers

Suppose that we have this matrix :

```
main = [10000   5   3   1;
5   5677    0   134;
1   1   456 3];
```

This method the most widely used method in econometrics and statistical problems.`X` is our data that we're searching for outliers in it.

```
X-mean(X)>= n*std(X)
```

So If this Inequality was true, That sample is outlier otherwise We will keep the sample.

Now my question. I want find outliers with these codes:

```
meann = mean(main);
stdd = std(main);
out = find(main-repmat(meann,size(main,1),1)>=repmat(2*stdd,size(main,1),1));
```

We are searching outliers in every column. `Out` should indicate index of outliers. In final step We should remove outliers in every column. Is any simpler function or method to do this in MAtLAB?

Thanks.

Comment: Outliers globally for that matrix or per column?

Comment: I think you should explain your logic because I feel like your code does not correctly implement what you're after. Are you saying that you want to find any number that is 2 standard deviations away from the mean (per column)?

Comment: Yes. That's true. I'm searching for outliers in every column. I know this code is not complete. It is only an idea. thanks.

Comment: @user2991243 I'm not saying anything about its completeness, I'm saying that you have not explained your definition of outlier and that you've posted potentially erroneous code so how is anyone supposed to know what you want. You must add an explanation in words, not just code.

Comment: Thank you. I added more information in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find 2 standard deviations away from the mean on a per column basis I would use `bsxfun` rather than `repmat` like this:

```
meann = mean(main)
stdd = std(main)

I = bsxfun(@gt, abs(bsxfun(@minus, main, meann)), 2*stdd)
```

I would stop at `I` as this will allow you to remove outliers. However you can call `find` it you like:

```
out = find(I)
```

Although to me it is more intuitive to do this:

```
I = bsxfun(@lt, meann + 2*stdd, main) | bsxfun(@gt, meann - 2*stdd, main)
```

I think your `repmat` solution is missing an `abs` btw

Answer (score 4):

A 2*sigma criterion is certainly simple, but the mean and the standard deviation are really sensitive to outliers. It follows that the `out` variable will thus be influenced, and in fact your code doesn't find any outlier in the given matrix.

To detect the outliers you can simply compare the values appearing in your matrix against the median, or adopt more refined criteria. There is a beautiful lecture explaining this at https://www.mne.psu.edu/me345/Lectures/outliers.pdf

Comment: Thant true but using `X-mean(X)> 2(or 3,...)*std` is the most widely used method in econometrics and statistical problems.

Comment: The lecture suggests using `|X-mean| > 1.9x * std` which is roughly 2.

Comment: @user2991243 You're missing and absolute there, i.e. the `|·|` in Yvon's comment. It's very important!

Answer (score 2):

Use a cell array if you want to remove certain elements from different columns.

```
main = rand(100,4);
main(10,1) = 10000;
main(40,2) = 4321;
main([10,20,30],3)=[938;10;4];


mu = num2cell(mean(main));
sig = num2cell(std(main));

m = num2cell(main,1);
ind = cellfun(@(x,m,s) find( bsxfun(@lt, abs( bsxfun(@minus,x,m) ), 2*s) ),...
    m, mu, sig, 'uni', 0);
data = cellfun(@(x,m,s) x( bsxfun(@lt, abs( bsxfun(@minus,x,m) ), 2*s) ),...
    m, mu, sig, 'uni', 0);
```

ps. your example is too small in size so there might be not enough samples to establish a threshold.