# How to detect and remove outliers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, outliers

I have a problem detecting outliers in a set of data. Let's say I have two arrays `x` and `y`, and y is a quadratic function of `x`. Some of the values of `y` do not follow this function. How can I detect them?

I tried the `rmoutliers` function, but it doesn't seem to solve this problem since it only deals with normally distributed data.

Basically, I am trying to study some material behavior. The behavior is represented by `y`. I use an optimization method to get the different values of `y` as a function of `x`.  Because sometimes the optimization doesn't yield accurate results, I get outliers.The relationship I am expecting should follow some nearly quadratic function, but the coefficients of this function are variable based one the provided set of data, so I can't use a certain function of `x` and use it to detect the outliers in the array of `y` values.

Comment: without a minimal example it's hard to tell if you are not using the rmoutliers  function properly, or that your definition for an outlier is different than mine...

Comment: This is my data set:
x = [-485.35 144.42 623.97 1178.63 1733.29 2287.95 2842.61]
y = [47.85 266.55 164.98 196.69 206.16 186.53 154.81]

Comment: maybe this can help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281160/statistical-outlier-detection-in-matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281160/statistical-outlier-detection-in-matlab)

Comment: the data you gave is meaningless without any additional information of the statistics, error bars etc. plotting it makes no sense and does not give us a minimal example to understand what you want.